# Force Heroku PHP application to reload included PHP script stored in Cloudinary

Tags: php, heroku, cloudinary

I have a PHP application running on Heroku.

In this application, there's a PHP script, `main.php`, that includes another PHP script, `to_be_included.php`, via `require_once()`.

`to_be_included.php` is stored on Cloudinary server (I have `allow_url_include` set to 1, so this is not a problem), and in `require_once()`, I provide the correct URL to the Cloudinary resource.

The problem is that my application always serves an old version of `to_be_included.php` that it fetched at some point in the past, and I cannot figure out for the love of me how to force my Heroku application to always fetch the latest version of it, manually or automatically!

I have even tried to clear the build cache as described on this link (https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) without success. Help me please!